# WPF Listview - get specific item and set its color

Tags: wpf, listview

I generate a ListView via Code like this:

myListView.Items.Add( personToAdd );

Now I want to do some long-term computation and while the computations lasts I want to disable the item. After the computation I want to enable the item again. How do I get the ListViewItem when I added objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the ListViewItem like this (here I get the selected ListViewItem):

```
object selectedEntry = (object)myListBox.SelectedItem;
ListBoxItem lbi = this.myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedEntry) as ListBoxItem;
```

But you also can get other items:

```
object selectedEntry = (object)myListBox.Items[int];
ListBoxItem lbi = this.myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedEntry) as ListBoxItem;
```